# how to remove an item from listview and database

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to delete an item from the listview and immediately from the Mysql database, the code is presented below to add these same items from the database
code in xaml:

```
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label x:Name="NUMER" TextColor="#9e0816" FontSize="Default" Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                                <Button x:Name="och" Text="Delete" Clicked="och_Clicked"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                        TextColor="#9e0816"
                                        CornerRadius="50"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        BorderColor="#9e0816"
                                        BorderWidth="1.5"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

code in c#:

```
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            con.cn.Open();
            command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT seriil FROM ISTORIYA", con.cn);
            var rd = command.ExecuteReader();
            hystories = new List<hystory>();
            while(rd.Read())
            {
                hystories.Add(new hystory
                {
                    Name = rd.GetString("seriil"),
                }
                    );
            }
            rd.Close();
            listview.ItemsSource = hystories;
            con.cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a `List<T>` then when you remove an item from that collection the `ListView` should update automatically

Comment: @Jason ok, it worked, but only for the collection, I don't understand how to work with the database, here's the code to delete: 
`
        {
            hystory hystorie = listview.SelectedItem as hystory;
            if (hystorie != null)
            {
                hystories.Remove(hystorie);
                listview.SelectedItem = null;
            }
            con.cn.Open();
            command = new MySqlCommand($"DELETE FROM ISTORIYA WHERE seriil = '{}'", con.cn);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.cn.Close();
        }
`

Comment: Removing from the collection and deleting from the db are two separate things.  Your code will need to do both

Comment: @Jason and there is no way to take information from the selected item for further communication with the deletion?

Comment: You still have a reference to the item you’re deleting

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MenuItem Clicked` event to activate the delete operation.Then you should get the `current selected item` as the parameter of method and then delete it in database and finally update current listview items.

Below is the xaml code:

```
     <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                      <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem  Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" Clicked="MenuItem_Deleted"></MenuItem>
                                </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                             <StackLayout>
                                    <Label x:Name="NUMER" TextColor="#9e0816" FontSize="Default" Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                             </StackLayout>
                       </ViewCell>
                   </DataTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
```

Below is the Pseudo-code for deleting the selected item,I use `SQLite` should be similar with Mysql.

```
         
        private async void MenuItem_Deleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //get the selected item
            User user = (sender as MenuItem).BindingContext as User;

            bool answer = await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please confirm the user "+ user.Name+ " will be removed!", "Yes", "No");

            if (answer)
            {
                UserDB db = await UserDB.Instance;

                //delete the selected item
                _ = await db.DeleteUserAsync(user);

                //update the listivew item
                List<User> a = await db.GetUserAsync();
                UserCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>(a);
                userinfodata.ItemsSource = UserCollection;
            }

        }
```

MS official reference link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/menuitem